# Does Amazon services support on-premise hosting?

Tags: chatbot, enterprise, amazon-lex

We intend to develop a enterprise Bot using amazon lex that will fetch response from a SQL server, and display result along with visual presentation. Does Lex support on premise deployment?
Will there be any challenges in using  `Lex vs Google Dialogflow (formerly known as api.ai)`?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The bot agent you will develop that will reside on AWS, you can access it on AWS Lex console and **you cannot have it on-premise**.

You can, however, use webhooks which you can have on-premise.

You can use amazon-lex to understand user query and match intent, once the intent is matched, you can perform the operations using if-else conditions and get data from your SQL server.
This way none of your data will be on AWS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you help me in understanding how do i connect with AWS services using webhook? Since i have not worked on this before.

Comment: follow this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-book-trip-create-integrate.html